# Using ISNULL on Result Set of Sybase ASE Stored Procedure

Tags: sap-ase

How to use ISNULL on the resultset of Sybase ASE Stored Procedure, or equivalent? Assumes you were not in control of the called stored procedure to fix the data at source. Is it possible to make the result set look like a table result set?

Version is 10.x

For example:

```
execute sp_get_some_nasty_data 'argument'
```

Returns:

```
DIRMAIL Direct Mail
DRIVBY  Drive By
REFERAL null
OTHER   Other
```

I'd like to use the 'code_value' if the 'display_value' is null perhaps:

```
select 
    isnull(2, 1)
from
    execute sp_get_some_nasty_data 'argument'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible, only by editing the procedure by inserting into a temp table.